# Where to archive web citations for molecular biology article?

Tags: molecular-biology

In 2013 I wrote a scientific paper in the field molecular biology. I needed to quote some webpages which I feared might disappear, e.g. amazon sales offers (it was a food related topic). So I archived them at Webcite (wecbitation.org), because it was recommended to me as an appropriate place for biosciences.

However, they stopped accepting new submissions. Where should I archive now ?

Comment: You can use the [Internet Archive's Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/) to get "permanent" links (as permanent as anything is on the internet) to just about any webpage, and I believe you can request indexing for pages that aren't already in the archive. Wikipedia uses this functionality for permalinks, for example.